# Transferring fetched data from tableview cell to another viewcontroller without segue

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

[here's my tableview function where i try to pass a reference for video object(which i'm fetching using youtube api) to DetailsViewController using navigationController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKVQ6.png)

[when i try to print an object inside a tableview, it shows me data i need, but only thing i get in detailsPageController is nil](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3PPB.png)

here's the code for tableView Function

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

```
    // Target viewcontroller to pass data
    let selectedVideo = videos[indexPath.row]
    let targetVC = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: DetailsViewController.identifier) as! DetailsViewController
    targetVC.video = selectedVideo
    print(targetVC.video?.title)
    
    
    // Navigate to the page
    NavigationManager.changeScene(from: self, to: .DetailsPage, with: .present)
}
```

code for DetailsViewController where i'm trying to print value of vide instance

class DetailsViewController: UIViewController{

```
// Self identifier
private(set) static var identifier = "DetailsViewController"

// MARK: - IBOutlets



// MARK: - Instances
public var video: Video?



// MARK: - Initialization

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    addSubViews()
    initializeStackView()
    initializeConstraints()
  
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    print(video?.title)
    
}
```

and this is just a static helper function to change scenes using navigation controller:

class NavigationManager {

```
enum TargetView {
    case mainPage
    case DetailsPage
}

enum TransitionStyle {
    case push, present
}

static func changeScene(from currentViewController: UIViewController, to chosenViewController: TargetView, with transitionStyle: TransitionStyle) {
    var targetVC: UIViewController!
    
    switch chosenViewController {
    case .mainPage:
        targetVC = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: MainViewController.identifier) as! MainViewController
    case .DetailsPage:
        targetVC = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: DetailsViewController.identifier) as! DetailsViewController
    }
    
    switch transitionStyle {
    case .push:
        currentViewController.navigationController?.pushViewController(targetVC, animated: true)
    case .present:
        currentViewController.navigationController?.present(targetVC, animated: true)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Copy/past code, not only screenshot. You set `video` to variable `targetVC`, but in the code of `NavigationManager.changeScene(from:to:with:)` you create a NEW `DetailsViewController` which hasn't a `video` set. `targetVC` is no the `DetailsViewController` instance that is shown. It's init/set, but isn't used.

Comment: sorry about that.it's the first time for me using this platform.i'll edit now.
new edit: thank you so much.you just saved me.i've been stuck on this problem for 2 days...